# How to extract text not inside parentheses?

Tags: excel, vba, string, textbox, powerpoint

I have written Excel VBA code to output a PowerPoint report. Part of the code is to create a table, then supply the data into it from the Excel.

For example, the data is the name of the employee together with their employee ID.

```
Aaron Montes (AMD, 785679), Peter Lim (PLM, 56987)
```

I do not want any information inside the parenthesis as well as the parenthesis itself.

I just need the employee's name.

Below is part of the code.
From the code below, the last part `.Text = Range("F1")` is where I will copy the data I will translate to PowerPoint.

```vb
Set myShape = myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.AddTable(10, 4, 50, 100, 800)
myShape.Table.Rows.Add
myShape.Height = 0

With myShape.Table
    .Cell(1, 1).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(1, 2)
    .Cell(1, 2).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(1, 3)
    .Cell(1, 3).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(1, 4)
    
    With .Cell(1, 4).Shape
        With .TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = "General Information"
            .Font.Size = 13
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
    End With

    With .Cell(2, 1).Shape
        With .TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = "FA Site"
            .Font.Size = 13
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
    End With
            
    With .Cell(2, 2).Shape
        With .TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = "Singapore"
            .Font.Size = 13
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
    End With
            
    With .Cell(2, 3).Shape
        With .TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = Range("F1")
            .Font.Size = 13
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: Please show us an example of the text in F1 that you're working with and mention whether it's consistent or not.  For example, is it always "Employee Name (some other stuff)" or might it be something else like "Employee name (stuff you don't want) followed by stuff you DO want"?

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for the reply. Example is like this --> Aaron Montes (AMD 785679), Peter Lim (PLM 56987). Most of the time is only a single name, two names are the maximum.

Comment: Hi Steve, sorry the data should be like this ---> Aaron Montes (AMD, 785679), Peter Lim (PLM, 56987)

Comment: In that case you'd need to modify the code I suggested to first check to see if there's a comma in the string (ie, IF INSTR(string, ",") > 0 THEN and if so, split the string at the comma and pass each portion to the code below, then reassemble them.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible answer, depending on your reply to my comment earlier, here's a function that will return the original text you pass to it with any text between open and close parentheses removed.

It's not very robust; you'll want to add further checks to make sure that, for example, there ARE both open and close parens in the string.

```
Function RemoveParens(sText As String) As String

    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim lParenStart As Long
    Dim lParenEnd As Long
    Dim sParentheticalText As String
    
    lParenStart = InStr(sText, "(")
    lParenEnd = InStr(sText, ")")
    
    sTemp = Mid$(sText, 1, lParenStart - 1)
    sTemp = sTemp & Mid$(sText, lParenEnd + 1)
    
    RemoveParens = sTemp
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. It has it's pros and cons.

Pros:

- *** Will work on multiple strings! Will not remove parts you want to keep in between bracketed areas, and will always remove all bracketed areas.
- Will not throw errors if nothing to remove (might also be a con in some situations)
- Short easy to use/edit function

Cons:

- You need to have a cell free to use for the calculations (Either A1 on a hidden sheet, or some cell you know is free
- Slow for large datasets, This takes about half a second per string on a slow work computer. if you're only dealing with =< 50 strings, great! otherwise this would take a few minutes to calculate. This may actually be the slowest way to do this calculation.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TextToStrip()
    Debug.Print StripOutParaText("Test (ouch) and Some ( dog) Number 1")
    ' Output = "Test and Some Number 1"
End Sub
Function StripOutParaText(RefText As String) As String
    Dim RG As Range
    Set RG = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")
    RG.Value = RefText
    RG.Replace " (*)", "", xlPart
    StripOutParaText = RG.Value
End Function
```